# Issue with shortcut created on Linux Desktop for shell script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, shortcut, desktop

I am new to Linux and I have a problem with the shortcut which I want to create on the Desktop for the script. I'm using just one line of the script because I want to understand how to create a shortcut that will run any .sh script from the Desktop position.
I allowed Launching and also I see for one second that terminal is open, but after it is closing and I don't see the output for example in the terminal...
Could you please advise???

[image: In the picture you will see the script and also [Desktop Entry]]

Answer (score 1):

After executing the script, the terminal will close. There are different ways to achieve what you want

- [Put `$SHELL` at the end of your script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20330/how-to-run-a-script-without-closing-the-terminal)
- Collect the output and display it in an UI element (e.g. [Zenity on Gnome](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put a `read -p "Press Enter to Continue"` message at the end of Shell Script or put a simple `sleep 5` i.e. delay of 5 seconds or any amount of delay you want

Example 1 with `read`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello World..."
read -p "Press Enter to Continue"
```

This will ask you for a key press and waits for you to press any key on keyboard

Example 2 with `sleep`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello World..."
sleep 5
```

This will simply wait for 5 seconds and automatically exits

Also, ensure that the `.desktop` file has executable permissions

`sudo chmod a+x /usr/share/applications/Hello.desktop` or `sudo chmod a+x ~/.local/share/applications/Hello.desktop` depending on where you have saved the `.desktop` file

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/a/230374/679241